# Microphone will not work

Tags: 14.04, microphone

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. The Microphone on Skype is effectively muted. System Preferences yields no luck either.
(My rep isn't good enough for me to embed images yet, so here is a link)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/44kpn8g8nkoy8fi/Multimedia%20Systems%20Selector.png?dl=0

The Test Pipeline gave a whole lot of alien static, but did pick up my voice in background, but it is not useful if I did get it to work and wanted to Skype someone.

Here's some terminal stuff that didn't help me:

```
adama@BSG:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel HDMI
                      HDA Intel HDMI at 0xe0610000 irq 64
 1 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xe0614000 irq 63
adama@BSG:~$ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC233 Analog [ALC233 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
adama@BSG:~$ arecord -d 10 /tmp/test-mic.wav
Recording WAVE '/tmp/test-mic.wav' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono
adama@BSG:~$ aplay /tmp/test-mic.wav
Playing WAVE '/tmp/test-mic.wav' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono
```

The wave file was empty. How can I fix this stuff? What else do I need to explore?

THANK YOU!